# SQL Transpose Single Column with Data to Single Row with Variable Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single column with data:

| Data |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| .. |

I want it to be a single row like so:

|  | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Columnx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | .. |

The number of columns is determined by the number of results from the query data. I need it to be in a row for other software to correctly read the required data.

Comment: What is the logic for ordering the data column and would it always contain just letters?

Comment: [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: This can be done in T-SQL and there are already [hundreds of questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql-server+dynamic+pivot) about dynamic pivoting of data, but I'd first ask do you really need to do this in T-SQL? The formatting of data is more often that not best left to the presentation layer.

Comment: Data is always a string value that contains both letters and numbers

Comment: I know I need to use the pivot function, however there are a varying number of rows depending on the query result

Comment: It's a lot of dynamic SELECT/PIVOT questions today. I answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74691637/sql-server-move-data-from-multiple-rows-to-one-row-to-new-columns-and-assign-co/74692778#74692778

Comment: This example seems way overcomplicated for what I'm trying to achieve here, no? I have not been able to find any examples of just a single column of data being dynamically pivoted.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be as complicated if you wanted the **row data** to become the **column names** after the pivot. But that's not what you're asking for. You are asking for the **row data** to be translated to **column data**. There might be an easier way to do it with `PIVOT or UNPIVOT` but I'm not familiar. Otherwise, this works exactly as you need:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
  [Data] nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO tableName
VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F')

--Get the maximum number of distinct data values so we know how many columns to create.
DECLARE @maxDataCount int;
SET @maxDataCount = (
  SELECT MAX(t.row_num)
  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Data]) as row_num
    FROM tableName
  ) as t );

--Create a variable to hold the dynamic query.
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(max);

--Create the first part of the SELECT statment with place holders
--where we can insert columns ({{0}}) and JOINS ({{1}})
SET @sqlText = '
  WITH prelim as (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Data]) as row_num
    FROM tableName
  )
  SELECT DISTINCT 1
    {{0}}
  FROM prelim as t
    {{1}}
  ';

--Setup loop variables.
DECLARE @loopCount int = 1;
DECLARE @loopCText nvarchar(50);

WHILE (@loopCount <= @maxDataCount)
BEGIN
  --Get a string for the loop count... pad it with zeros if multi-digits.
  SET @loopCText = RIGHT(
    '0000000000' + CAST(@loopCount as nvarchar(10))
    , LEN(CAST(@maxDataCount as nvarchar(50)))
  );

  --Add a SELECT entry for this loop instance.
  SET @sqlText = REPLACE(@sqlText, '{{0}}', '
    , t' + @loopCText + '.[data] as Column' + @loopCText + '
    {{0}}
  ');

  --Add a JOIN entry for this loop instance.
  SET @sqlText = REPLACE(@sqlText, '{{1}}', '
    LEFT OUTER JOIN prelim as t' + @loopCText + '
      --ON t' + @loopCText + '.[Data] = t.[Data]
      ON t' + @loopCText + '.row_num = ' + CAST(@loopCount as nvarchar(10)) + '
    {{1}}
  ');

  --SELECT @sqlText;  --For debugging
  SET @loopCount = @loopCount + 1;
END

--Post Loop Cleanup... remove template place holders.
SET @sqlText = REPLACE(@sqlText, '{{0}}', '');
SET @sqlText = REPLACE(@sqlText, '{{1}}', '');

EXEC(@sqlText);
```

| (No column name) | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | D | E | F |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fuK_3720)

Comment: As you suspected, there is a simpler way of doing it by building the underlying query using `STRING_AGG` rather than with loops, and using conditional aggregation rather than joins - [example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ToNWUjob)